Why does a capacitor act as an open circuit under a DC circuit?
In the case of bypassing/decoupling capacitors under DC circuits, I know that they act as open circuits when connected between Vcc and ground, which is why the two can be shorted, but why/how exactly do they do this? What mechanisms are involved? What is actually happening?

You say, "...the two can be shorted..." What do you mean by "shorted?" In normal use, a "short circuit" is a fault condition. It's an accidental, direct connection between two nodes in a circuit that are not supposed to be directly connected to each other. What does a capacitor have to do with a "short circuit?" Can you add a circuit diagram to your question that shows the capacitor that you are asking about? Can you add a diagram that shows the "short circuit?"

You can see from the other answers why it appears that way mathematically.
Physically, it's because it is an open circuit!
Consider the most basic form of a capacitor, the parallel plate capacitor. All real capacitors are similar to this, though it may be hard to see it because there are many layers, the layers are coiled up or there is more complexity to the layers. So here is a basic representation of a capacitor (image from the above link to Wikipedia):

The "Dielectric" material is an insulator (something like air, plastic or ceramic, typically). So there is no conductive path between the plates, just maybe a tiny bit of unwanted leakage through the insulator. It's no different, except in scale, from two wires in space with insulators between them in the rest of your circuit. That's the so-called stray capacitance- like tiny capacitors between various parts of the circuit that we can often ignore at low frequencies (because they have tiny capacitance and other things that are effectively in parallel have much lower impedance at the frequencies of interest).
It's more difficult to explain physically why it acts as a capacitor, especially with high-permittivity dielectrics such as X7R but fortunately that wasn't your question. Feynman does it in one of his famous lectures.

Also note that the 2D sketch of the parallel plane capacitor resembles the capacitor symbol in diagrams. Coincidence?

In any realisable circuit, there is resistance in the paths connecting a capacitor to a voltage source, a resistance represented by R1 here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When the voltage source V1 is initially connected, and the capacitor has no charge, \$V_C=0V\$. Importantly, though, by KVL the remaining 12V must  exist across R1, and this will result in an initial current \$I\$, calculable with Ohm's law:
$$ I_0 = \frac{12V}{0.1\Omega} = 120A $$
Since there's a current flowing, the capacitor is charging, and its voltage is rising:

By KVL again, this means that the voltage across R1 is decreasing, meaning that current \$I\$ around the loop is decreasing too:

Eventually, after the capacitor has charged up to the full 12V, the voltage across R1 has fallen to zero, so current will eventually settle at zero. Unless the voltage source changes, current will remain at zero for all eternity. This is the "DC" state shown on the ammeter and voltmeters above.
The conclusion, then, is that current only flows when the voltage source changes (from 0V to 12V in this example), but when the source stays fixed (DC), long-term current through the capacitor will always by zero, so we say it has "infinite impedance" at DC.
When there is a change in conditions, such as an IC suddenly demanding more current from the supply, resistance and inductance in the supply and its wiring prevent the supply from responding instantly to the change, and supply voltage will fluctuate. A capacitor across the supply mitigates this, by being a short-term source of energy, able to supply a lot of current for a short duration, until the power supply "catches up".
Consequently capacitor voltage fluctuates less under changing (AC) load conditions, while capacitor current fluctuates more, corresponding to having a lower impedance \$\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}\$ at AC.

Current into or out of a capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of the voltage across its terminals. Vcc and ground are normally unchanging; decoupling capacitors are added to help them remain so. If Vcc/the supply voltage sags because, say, a load gets suddenly turned on, a capacitor between Vcc and ground will release some of its stored charge to help the (possibly distant) voltage supply maintain supply voltage constant.

The physics/nature of a capacitor are such that the current through them is proportionate to the rate of change of the voltage applied across their terminals. Since the rate of change is definitionally zero under DC conditions, no current flows through them, and so they act similar to (analytically indistinguishably from) an open circuit in that condition.

No electrons can flow from one side of a non-leaky capacitor to another.  When current flows through a capacitor is that an electron which flows into the negative plate will be attacted to the portion closest to the positive plate, and its presence would push electrons in the positive plate to the parts furthest away from the negative plate.  This would then cause the positive plate to be more willing to give up electrons than it otherwise would be.  Note, however, that if the negative plate gains an electron and the positive plate loses one, this will mean the negative plate will have one more electron without a corresponding proton, and the positive plate will have one more proton without a corresponding electron.  While the aforementioend effects can somewhat counter-balance the extent to which the excess electrons in the negative plate would push away any electrons that might try to enter, and the shortage of electrons in the positive plate would draw back electrons that try to leave, such counter-balancing will become less and less effective as the electron surpluse and deficit increase.

The capacitor is charge storing device. It has a resistance given by Xc=1/2pifC- which suggests that this resistance a capacitor offers to any sort of voltage/current source is dependent on the frequency of the incoming voltage/current.
As DC current and Voltages have no frequency component in them, f is essentially zero. f=0, implies Xc=1/0 = infinity. So capacitors offer absolutely high resistance to DC and hence behave as an open circuit.
Hope this helps.

Resistance and impedance are not the same thing.


Why does a capacitor act as an open circuit under a DC circuit?

It doesn't.
When the circuit is closed, a current circulates until the capacitor is fully loaded with electrons. This is because electrons coming from the negative side of the source accumulate on one plate of the capacitor, creating a negative electrostatic charge. This charge repels electrons on the other plate, creating a positive charge, hence a voltage (difference of potentials) develops between the plates.
This continues until the potential of each plate equals the potential on the respective source electrode. At this point the voltage between the plates is the source voltage. No force can move the electrons further, no current exists, hence for DC this is the end of the process, and it looks now the capacitor is an open circuit.
On AC the source polarity is reversed after some time, so the charges can evacuate the plates, and the plates after being at the same potential (voltage 0, like an "empty" capacitor) start loading with inverted polarities (negative voltage between the plates), like if it was DC, but with the source polarity reversed.
When the capacitor is fully loaded this stops, like it did previously. The capacitor is now waiting for the next cycle of the AC source (if the frequency is higher, the capacitor cannot reach its full capacity within half the period, but the principle is the same).
So the behavior is the same in AC and DC, but in DC it occurs only once, because the polarity is kept unchanged.

What mechanisms are involved?

Only the static forces existing between electrons. Particles of the same charge sign (positive or negative) repel each other. This repulsive force equalizes the density of electrons in a conductor, and repels electrons in other conductors in the close vicinity.
A capacitor is made of two conductors (plates). When it is connected to a source, the source provides additional electrons on the negative electrode. The plate on this side sees its electron density increased. This in turn repels electrons on the plate connected to the positive electrode. The accumulation of electrons stops when the plate potential is equal to the negative electrode potential. Its the difference of potentials (known as voltage) which moves electrons.
The capacity of the capacitor is a function of the plate area (a larger area has accumulated more electrons when the density has been equalized) and the distance between the plates (a shorter distance allows for the repulsive force to be more efficient in repulsing electrons on the positive side, it's Coulomb's law)
Many circuits are actually (bad) capacitors as the effect I described doesn't require to use plates, two conductors close enough show the same effect. Hence a pair of conductors can be represented as having a parasitic capacitance (as well as a parasitic inductance).

Your answer depends on the idea that "DC" means, "currents flow in only one direction/voltages don't change sign." But that's a rudimentary idea. To somebody with a mathematical understanding of how circuits behave (an electrical engineer) "DC" refers to an unchanging component of a signal. If you connect a capacitor to a battery through a resistor, the rising voltage and the decaying current don't change direction, but they do change over time. They're "AC" components of the circuit's transient behavior. After it settles down though, there will be nothing left but the steady, "DC" state.

@Ohm'sLawman: The OP asks about a capacitor in a DC circuit, not about a capacitor in null current condition. To me the transient state is part of the answer.

I'm guessing that the real answer to the OP's question would talk about filters. Sounds like the capacitor in the question is part of a (possibly crude) low-pass filter in an AC-to-DC power supply. Although I spent many years working in an open office, surrounded by EEs, I was not one of them—I was just their pet software geek—and so I will not attempt to answer the question in terms of the theory of electronic filters.

The OP mentions decoupling/coupling capacitors used to block or pass the DC offset, so yes it's either a high-pass or a low-path filter.

A capacitor connected to a voltage source in a steady state is charged to the voltage of the source. Thus, in the loop, it acts as an oppositely connected clone voltage source. As a result, no current flows, creating the illusion of an open circuit. Whether the capacitor is there or removed makes no difference.

A capacitor is not well-described as an open circuit even in DC situations.  I'd rather describe it as a charge-controlled ideal voltage source in that it can deliver and accept arbitrarily high currents at the cost of adapting its voltage depending on the delivered charge.
That means that paralleling it with a voltage source of different voltage is a bad idea at least momentarily, and power supplies with large capacitors go to some pain to avoid that scenario with inrush current protective circuits.
Particularly the toroid transformers popular with power audio amplifiers have a reputation for needing inrush current protection, not because of any inherent problem of their own but because they have so little stray inductance that they essentially hand through the sieve capacitors of the power supply right to their primary side without significant mitigation, essentially shorting the primary momentarily.
Decoupling capacitors act as local parallel voltage sources that can supply short-term current at the circuit voltage in case that resistance and/or inductance of the leads to the principal voltage source could cause the supply not to keep up with current spikes.
Since delivering or receiving charges changes the nominal voltage of the decoupling capacitor as a voltage source, it is then topped up again by the main voltage source after it has pitched in momentarily.
